# gcloud Firestore import: PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I am trying to import a bucket containing a Firestore database export into antoher Firebase project. I have been following [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data) on how to do this.

When running the `gcloud firestore import`, I run into the following issue:

> ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.import) PERMISSION_DENIED: Service account does not have access to Google Cloud Storage file: /bucket/EXPORT_PREFIX.overall_export_metadata. See https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#permissions for a list of permissions needed. Error details: service-XXX@gcp-sa-firestore.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

I did however use the following command to grant access to the bucket:

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:SOURCE_PROJECTID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:admin gs://bucket_name
```

This did not give me any error whatsoever, so I assume it ran as expected. I triple checked and believe I was working in the correct projects while using these commands.

I think that perhaps the `import` command is ran with another service account than `SOURCE_PROJECTID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:admin`, but am unsure about this or on how to ensure the correct service account is being used.

Any help on resolving this would be highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message appears to include the Service Account in question:

```
Error details:
service-XXX@gcp-sa-firestore.iam.gserviceaccount.com
does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

I think you need to:

```sh
gsutil iam ch \
serviceAccount:[service-XXX]@gcp-sa-firestore.iam.gserviceaccount.com:objectViewer \
gs://[bucket-name]
```

Replacing `[service-XXX]` and `[bucket-name]`

Comment: I had this same error today when doing the same thing and setting permissions on this generic service account as @DazWilkin mentioned was the fix. I am not sure why gcloud wasn't using the project service account like it normally does.