# Firestore Import Fails with Permission Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

When trying to import Firestore documents using a Cloud Function, the operation fails with a permission error. The Firestore import is attempted using the following code snippet:

```js
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const gcloudFirestoreClient = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();

const bucketName = 'auth-firestore-backup';
const name = 'v03';

const projectID = process.env.GCP_PROJECT || process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT;
const importName = `projects/${projectID}/databases/(default)/documents:import`;
const inputUriPrefix = `gs://${bucketName}/${name}/`;

await gcloudFirestoreClient.importDocuments({
    name: importName,
    inputUriPrefix,
    collectionIds: []
});
```

The inputUriPrefix is set to the correct Google Cloud Storage location where the Firestore export files are stored. The bucket has uniform access control and the service account running the Cloud Function has been granted the Storage Admin role on the bucket and `roles/datastore.importExportAdmin` to.

Efforts to Resolve:

- Checked the permissions on the bucket and confirmed that the service account has Storage Admin role.
- Granted additional roles (roles/datastore.owner and roles/datastore.importExportAdmin) to the service account to ensure it has the necessary permissions for Firestore import operations.
- Verified the inputUriPrefix is correctly pointing to the location of the Firestore export files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gcloud Firestore import: PERMISSION\_DENIED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71335311/gcloud-firestore-import-permission-denied)